# Calculating UV Coordinates in domain shader

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl

I was trying to implement the terrain tutorial in Introduction to game programming by frank luna. I succeeded to implement it using the effect file.

When I try to separate the Vertex, hull, domain and pixel shaders, I got a very strange behavior in the terrain textures. After debugging I got that the problem is in calculating the UV texture coordinates in the domain shader.

Here is how I calculate the UV coordinates.

```
[domain("quad")]    
DomainOut main(PatchTess patchTess,
float2 uv : SV_DomainLocation,
const OutputPatch<HullOut, 4> quad)
{
DomainOut dout;

// Bilinear interpolation.
dout.PosW = lerp(
    lerp(quad[0].PosW, quad[1].PosW, uv.x),
    lerp(quad[2].PosW, quad[3].PosW, uv.x),
    uv.y);

dout.Tex = lerp(
    lerp(quad[0].Tex, quad[1].Tex, uv.x),
    lerp(quad[2].Tex, quad[3].Tex, uv.x),
    uv.y);

// Tile layer textures over terrain.
dout.TiledTex = dout.Tex * 50.0f;

dout.TiledTex = dout.Tex*50.0f;

// Displacement mapping
dout.PosW.y = gHeightMap.SampleLevel(samHeightmap, dout.Tex, 0).r;

// NOTE: We tried computing the normal in the shader using finite difference, 
// but the vertices move continuously with fractional_even which creates
// noticable light shimmering artifacts as the normal changes.  Therefore,
// we moved the calculation to the pixel shader.  

// Project to homogeneous clip space.
dout.PosH = mul(float4(dout.PosW, 1.0f), gViewProj);

return dout;
}
```

I am using quads for the domain shader.

After debugging using graphics analyzer, I got that in the domain shader the data is different from effect file from the domain shader I implemented altough the same code is used in both files.

What can be the problem?

[image: This is the image of my implementation]

[image: This is the original image]

*I have an update to share with you, The data stream that enters to the domain shader is different from the effect file from the separated files. It is not the equation for the calculation.*

*What makes the data stream different, is there any way to change the order of patches enters the domain shader from the Hull shader.*

This is the pixel shader code:

```
    Texture2DArray gLayerMapArray : register(t3);
    Texture2D gBlendMap : register(t1);

    SamplerState samLinear
    {
        Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;

    AddressU = WRAP;
    AddressV = WRAP;
    AddressW = WRAP;
};

struct DomainOut
{
    float4 PosH     : SV_POSITION;
    float3 PosW     : POSITION;
    float2 Tex      : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TiledTex : TEXCOORD1;
};


float4 main(DomainOut pin) : SV_Target
{
    //
    // Texturing
    //
    float4 c0 = gLayerMapArray.Sample(samLinear, float3(pin.TiledTex, 0.0f));
    float4 c1 = gLayerMapArray.Sample(samLinear, float3(pin.TiledTex, 1.0f));
    float4 c2 = gLayerMapArray.Sample(samLinear, float3(pin.TiledTex, 2.0f));
    float4 c3 = gLayerMapArray.Sample(samLinear, float3(pin.TiledTex, 3.0f));

    // Sample the blend map.
    float4 t = gBlendMap.Sample(samLinear, pin.Tex);

    // Blend the layers on top of each other.
    float4 texColor = c0;
    texColor = lerp(texColor, c1, t.r);
    texColor = lerp(texColor, c2, t.g);
    texColor = lerp(texColor, c3, t.b);
    return texColor;
}
```

Comment: This looks fine. What problems do you encounter?

Comment: I have added links in the original question for images of the problem. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Do your input quads have valid texture coordinates? It looks as if they are all zero.

Comment: Yes, the quad uv has values (0,0) , (0.03125,0) , (0, 0.03125) , (0.03215, 0.03215)

Comment: Can you verify that somehow? E.g. map the texture coordinates to color. There might be a broken link that prevents the texture coordinates from reaching the shader. Can you show the part of the fragment shader that samples the texture?

Comment: After further debugging in the domain shader, I found that the data from the effect file is exactly in the effect file and in the domain shader file. You are right the problem may be from the sampling in the pixel shader. I updated the question with the pixel shader file.

Comment: The code looks quite ok. Can you see what you get when you return `pin.TiledTex` from the pixel shader? If that looks weird, try `pin.Tex`. If that still looks weird, try passing on `quad[0].Tex` etc.

Comment: I tried of all of these, I found the problem but I don't know how to solve it. The problem is in the sampling. I made another new project using effect file and I multiplied the tex cord by 10 in the vertex shader and let the raterization interpolated it, the texture is repeated 10 times on simple box. When I made the same test with my separated vertex and pixel shader code the texture got wired. I don't know why. Does the effect file add some defaults to the sampling. I don't know.

Comment: So, the texture coordinates you get in the pixel shader are ok? Is that what your tests confirmed? My guess is that the texture coordinates are constant, such that the sampler takes the highest mip level. Can you explicitly ask for level zero (using `SampleLevel`)?

Comment: I already tried sample level but not working

Comment: Thanks Nico for your support. You helped me a lot to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution is that I should set the sampler from c++ code even if you have a sampler in the shader. I don't know why but this solved the problem.